# how to ignore "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. ts(2589)" typescript error?

Tags: typescript

After update to Typescript 3.5 i'm getting a lot of "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)" errors.

How can I ignore them?

Where the code happens (using [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/))

```
import { Connection, Repository, Entity, BaseEntity,  createConnection } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
    public id: number;
}

class Test {
    async test() {
        const connection: Connection = await createConnection();
        const repo1                       = connection.getRepository(MyEntity); 
        const repo2: Repository<MyEntity> = connection.getRepository(MyEntity); // only here cast the error above
    }
}
```

I noted that only the `repo2` initialization cast the error message.

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve].  As of now [I can't reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQgOzQUwMY2OgGjgCVNIBnYGaATyIFE08Y64AhAQ3M0edbmxRMHGJlQYcedHAC+cAGZQIIOAHIWYTNBCqA3AFgAUEYACvKjQAUASiPYANl3JwAsjXMs4mAB6i0AE2dObg8aRCM4SLgwAFcAI3tgbDhgfwAuODQYkDjMKDgAXjgARgAmAGYDQxkjO0dyZwAVTHJ4BAiorho0ZNFWm3DDKOGBdFbRiVx8NAzxLCnpIo4Adw4qASERMXR5qTQbKpGo7DH4IUhio6vryKKTyb2AOgBzTBhSCipaSzdQ6104B0jvdxucIKUMh8IJRqFAaAAeX5MCwAPkKE120xebyhMO+SL4-zgAHpiXB0PYwgALPKYARceAwGleKBKfIcOIQABumCBsiMMiAA).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

... You should see an error:

```
type Test00<T1 extends any[], T2 extends any[]> =
    Reverse<Cast<Reverse<T1>, any[]>, T2>
```

> Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. ts(2589)

It happens when TS decides that types become too complex to compute (ie).
The solution is to compute the types that cause problems step by step:

```
type Test01<T1 extends any[], T2 extends any[]> =
    Reverse<Reverse<T1> extends infer R ? Cast<R, any[]> : never, T2>
```

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30188#issuecomment-478938437

Comment: I appreciate this comment, but it does not shows me how to ignore the error.

Comment: @DanielSantos But it offers an alternative way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Please, provide an working example for the code provided above.

Comment: @DanielSantos I can't reproduce the error you see so it's hard to imagine fixing it

Answer (score 16):

I managed to make the error go away while still being able to compute the type properly with the usage of **@ts-ignore**. An example can be found in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYChIE8AHTUAMXkwBsATAaUzwB4B5UTAD0k2SulACVMAYwxUG0SOnjJEAGlABXZAGs0Ad2QA+DaAC8oAN6gA2kvqgpoU3lQAzUEwC6ALnsn6D1hy49+QkWIkpWQVlNU1QAH5QAAMAEn1xSWlQADJLegBfADp4xKDU0nJqOkYmNzwHDQzo0BcrUAzy23sHAG5cQmIAUTYAQwBbAgpiPUMqVEQXACIAKV7BJTwpuUhUPGgXQ37UeWhMTdBhCgxpxHRepZXMTEgAC2nVW-hOKYa5ACNUZH2DQ9Rj9AuADk7wo8kwQLkBHgg2GG1AEnBb1AnzYB0E8neP0M716FAowKwVCBDVJGQa7XwREKlFo9AATLoacV6AwegMhpgNO1sNgQKAAIKQTiDGC8-lU4hkWklZieTjcXgCYToUR5aRyRQqVDqLRMuIJQLJNJkdDiAAymAAbpRZUwqjlDUlEAUAMp+biWm0UO0O3JGl1pAAqT1VXttrPt1R5Es6zLppXl3iVflVAWdmtCOs02j0LHYCp8yv8fLAoHMyBsmHQoBKMlL5ZC2vUDY0DfLURKScVoHViHbjaiZRKHgLyd8KrVAczzc0A8bkXjdvKlXnjZcJTXLm+NvQA7q9GaTHaQA), in a nutshell if you remove the `// @ts-ignore`, in a full-fledged development environment, line I imagine that the code would not compile.